# How to check if there is something on the clipboard

Tags: ios, swift, clipboard

How can I check if there is something on the clipboard?

**if there is something on the clipboard, then perform a certain action, and if not, another action (as shown in the code for an example)**

```
if (if in the clipboard, that is, then open the VC) {
        let modalViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Clipboard") as? ClipboardViewController
        modalViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(modalViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else (if the clipboard is empty then) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Clipboard is Empty", message: "It's recommended you bring your towel before continuing.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `UIPasteboard`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [UIPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard) class.

```
if let value = UIPasteboard.general.string {
    // there is value in clipboard
} else {
    // clipboard is empty
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since iOS 10 you should use `UIPasteboard` properties like `hasStrings` to check if a specific data type is present on Pasteboard:

```
var hasStrings: Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether or not the 
>   strings property contains a nonempty array.

---

**From the docs:**

> Starting in iOS 10, the UIPasteboard class provides properties for
>   directly checking whether specific data types are present on a
>   pasteboard, described in Checking for Data Types on a Pasteboard. Use
>   these properties, rather than attempting to read pasteboard data, to
>   avoid causing the system to needlessly attempt to fetch data before it
>   is needed or when the data might not be present. For example, you can
>   use the new hasStrings property to determine whether to present a
>   string-data Paste option in the user interface, using code like this:

```
if UIPasteboard.general.hasStrings {
    // Enable string-related control...
    if let string = UIPasteboard.general.string {
        // use the string here
    }
}
```

---

There is another few properties to check for data types;

```
var hasColors: Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether or not the 
>   colors property contains a nonempty array.

---

```
var hasImages: Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether or not the images property contains a nonempty array.

---

```
var hasURLs: Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether or not the 
>   urls property contains a nonempty array.