# Detect paste event in UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

How can I detect if the user pasted something into a `UITextField`?

All answers I'm finding online and on StackOverflow pertain to `UITextView`s.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960062/5078779) is for UITextField even though the question asks about UITextView.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to override `UIResponderStandardEditActions` paste method on your `UITextField` delegate:

```
override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
    print("do someting")
    super.paste(sender)
}
```

Comment: how can i get access to the text in the clipboard/paste buffer?

Comment: I found out I can get access to that through `UIPasteboard.general.string`

Comment: @frlzjosh make sure to check if the pasteboard `hasString` before trying to access it [How to check if there is something on the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134316/2303865)

Comment: whatever I type in the given method get pasted in the textfield. I can't perform any action.

Comment: @sahib well this doesn't do anything other than printing "do something". Not sure why it would affect the textfield behavior